# Change Member Group by non SA

Tags: solspace-user, member-management, signup

I'm in the the throws of building a site that is based purely on membership. Everything is sweet with pretty much all activity (post, comment, edit, delete etc) NOT requiring anyone to go to the CP it's all done with a mixture of modules (User, Messaging + Safecraker).

Now I'm at the "signup" process and I'd like to make it a tad simpler for admins to promote OR ban new signups WITHOUT going to the CP to do so.

I was planning on:

1. User signs up and goes into "pending"
2. Redirected to FreeForm page where they complete a little "about me" form and include their signup name in hidden field. This is instead of a new SAFE entry/page.
3. Admins notified, go to a special page and view applications (freeform entries)
4. Read the entry and if they sound legitimate, *somehow* using a select dropdown or checkbox, hit either "promote" or "deny" which alters the member member_group to base member or banned.

That was the plan but am open to ways where a NON SA can alter members member_group just like they can in the CP with the right privileges.

*The reason for a Freeform post is to further validate their viability as members not spammers.*

Solspace User allows editing of member_group but only by SA but I dont want to give SA to a group of peeps that ostensibly dont need it when 99% of the site is controlled via front end.

I could work it in reverse and have users fill out a Freeform with details then send them an invite key BUT Solspace User "keys" need to be generated by SA :(